# Mapping markers on Google Maps

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, google-maps, geocoding

I am looking to map about 800 markers on a Google map.  I have a csv file with addresses, including latitude and longitude coordinates.  I would like to be able to somehow upload this file to Google Maps resulting in a map displaying all of my markers.  This process will be automated, where a windows service (or via Sql Server Integration Services) will upload the address data to some url, effectively updating the markers on a map, which is embeded on an Asp.Net page on my site.

Does anyone know of a simple way this can be accomplished?  Are there any tools out there that can already do this?  I've looked at batchgeo.com and there file upload feature, but I don't think their tool can be automated.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just to use [google maps api v3](http://code.google.com/intl/cs/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html) to display the markers? With 800 markers you probably would like to use [marker clustering](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/toomanymarkers.html) e.g. using [markerclusterer](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/docs/reference.html)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I checked out marker clustering.  In the end that is probably what I'll have to go with.  However, I would like to be able to accomplish this with as little coding as possible.  If I can find a tool/app that can do this for me, that would be great and would save me a lot of time.  If I cant, well, I guess I'll have to resort to the google maps api.

Comment: Maybe you could try to use some frameworks that use google maps like [gmap3](http://gmap3.net/), or maybe there exist some server side frameworks for your asp that can accomplish this. Nevertheless using google api v3 and markerclusterer directly is quite easy so maybe it's the most efficient solution rather then choose & learn other frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

800 markers is a lot for one map, especially without marker clustering. Do you think maybe something like [Google Fusion Tables](http://www.google.com/fusiontables/Home/) would work?  It's pretty easy, doesn't require much in terms of coding, and I'm fairly certain you can update records via URLs.  You can upload your initial CSV file to it, too, and then display the points on a Google Map.